# SwiftData query for string in relationship

Tags: swift, swift-data

I'm trying to implement a search function in SwiftUI with SwiftData. I'm struggling to to query for the `recognizedText` in my `DocumentImage`. On the list where I want to filter I have several `Document` that hold n `DocumentImage`. I found out that it might not work with the `#Predicate` macro.

But how could I achieve that?

```
init(searchTerm: String) {
    if !searchTerm.isEmpty {
        let predicate = #Predicate<Document> {
            $0.title.localizedStandardContains(searchTerm)
        }
        _documents = Query(filter: predicate)
    }
}
```

```
@Model
final class Document {
    var timestamp = Date.now
    var title = Date.now.dateString + "-" + String(localized: "Untitled")

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \DocumentImage.document)
    var documentImagesStorage: [DocumentImage]? = []

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Tag.document)
    var tagsStorage: [Tag]? = []

    init(documentImages: [DocumentImage]) {
        self.documentImagesStorage = documentImages
    }
}

@Model
final class DocumentImage {
    var document: Document?

    @Attribute(.externalStorage)
    var imageData: Data = Data()
    var recognizedText: [String]?
    var order: Int?

    init(imageData: Data, recognizedText: [String], order: Int = 0) {
        self.imageData = imageData
        self.recognizedText = recognizedText
        self.order = order
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this can be done but could you at least explain how you want to search the array? There no attempt shown so it's not clear what the required logic is.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the idea was to join the string array and then make a localizedStringContains on it. I already had several failing attempts to get this to work. I don't even remember what I tried. I want go through all related documentImages and if it contains the string then it should match.